# (n+1)-dim boolean masking a n-dim array with array of means as desired output

Tags: numpy

I have this 2D-array with values

```
values=np.random.rand(3,3)
```

and a 3D-array with boolean masks

```
masks = np.random.rand(5,3,3)>0.5
```

My desired output is an array of the means of the masked values. I can do that with:

```
np.array([values[masks[i]].mean() for i in range(len(masks))])
```

Is there a more efficient way of achieving that ?

Comment: Shouldn't `values` be something like `values=np.random.rand(3,5)`?

Comment: Indeed. I changed masks instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `matrix-multplication` with [`np.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) like so -

```
# Counts of valid mask elements for each element in output
counts = masks.sum(axis=(1,2))

# Use matrix multiplication to get sum of elementwise multiplications.
# Then, divide by counts for getting average/mean values as final output.
out = np.dot(masks.reshape(masks.shape[0],-1),values.ravel())/counts
```

One can also use [`np.tensordot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) to perform the dot-product without reshaping, like so -

```
out = np.tensordot(masks,values,axes=([1,2],[0,1]))/counts
```

---

For generic cases involving functions like `min()` & `max()`, you can broadcast `values` to a `3D` array version of the same shape as `masks` and with elements set from `values` at `True` positions, otherwise set as `NaNs`. Then, you can use functions like [`np.nanmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.nanmin.html) and [`np.nanmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.nanmax.html) that allows users to perform such operations ignoring the `NaNs`, thus replicating our desired behavior. Thus, we would have -

```
# Masked array with values being put at True places of masks, otherwise NaNs
nan_masked_values = np.where(masks,values,np.nan)

# For performing .min() use np.nanmin
out_min = np.nanmin(nan_masked_values,axis=(1,2))

# For performing .max() use np.nanmax
out_max = np.nanmax(nan_masked_values,axis=(1,2))
```

Thus, the original `.mean()` calculation could be performed with [`np.nanmean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) like so -

```
out_mean = np.nanmean(nan_masked_values,axis=(1,2))
```

Comment: This is interesting and involves maths I'm not comfortable with. Can something similar be done to compute minimums and maximums instead of means ?

Comment: The second part of the answer is more suitable to my maths level. I guess it is slower for computing means, isn't ?

Comment: @nicoco Yeah for `mean` calculations, I would advise going with the first approach, if possible.

Comment: Unfortunately I simplified the problem. I have 4D arrays and 5D masks, I'm trying to figure out which values I have to change...

Comment: @nicoco I would think the only change would be that `axis=(1,2)` would become `axis=(3,4)`.

Comment: Why do you specify `values*masks` in `np.where(masks,values*masks,np.nan)` ? I have the same results with `masks` only, so I'm wondering.

Comment: @nicoco Ah good find! Yes, I forgot that `values` would be broadcasted inside `np.where`. Thanks! Updated my post.