# Different output in my script and in console using dot product

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I've been trying to solve this for more than 2 hours.

I have written a script where I put some debugging `print`s

```
...
print(array)
print(m)
print(np.dot(m.ravel(),array.ravel()))
...
```

When I launch it I have this output:

```
$ ./test.py 
[[    0     0     0     0     0     0     0]
 [    0     0     0     0     0     0     0]
 [    0     0     0     0     0     0     0]
 [    0     0     0 20303 20303 20303 20303]
 [20303 20303 20303 20303 20303 20303 20303]
 [20303 20303 20303 20303 20303 20303 20303]
 [20303 20303 20303 20303 20303 20303 20303]]
[[False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False  True False False]
 [False False  True False  True False False]
 [False False False  True False False False]
 [False False False False False False False]]
15676
```

When I try to reproduce this behaviour in a python console, I have a different result for the dot product:

```
$ /usr/bin/python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array=np.array([[    0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0],
[    0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0],
[    0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0],
[    0,     0,     0, 20303, 20303, 20303, 20303],
[20303, 20303, 20303, 20303, 20303, 20303, 20303],
[20303, 20303, 20303, 20303, 20303, 20303, 20303],
[20303, 20303, 20303, 20303, 20303, 20303, 20303]])
>>> 
>>> m=np.array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
[False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
[False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False],
[False, False, False,  True, False, False, False],
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False]])
>>> np.dot(m.ravel(),array.ravel())
81212
```

What can cause this ? By the way, `81212` is the result I expect here and really don't understand what's happening in my script.

Comment: try running `/usr/bin/python3 test.py` just to be sure.

Comment: What python interpreter `test.py` is running with? What is the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) of `test.py`?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python3` :(

Comment: What is `np.__version__`, both in your script and in the interactive interpreter?

Comment: What about `np.__file__`? Is it _exactly_ the same version, build, file etc.?

Comment: `/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py` in both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my script, the dtype of `array` was `uint16` while it was `int64` when I created it in the console. Converting its type solved the problem, but I don't see why it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Not actually *solving* the problem, but maybe a workaround:

[`np.ravel`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) has changed slightly in NumPy 1.10, maybe this is causing the "weird" behaviour:

> As of NumPy 1.10, the returned array will have the same type as the input array. (for example, a masked array will be returned for a masked array input)

But do you really need `np.ravel` in this case? What about just using [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) and summing up the results:

```
>>> print(array[m].sum())
81212
```

If this is what you wanted to achieve in the first place, this method is probably even more "pythonic" than `np.dot`ting the flattened arrays.

Comment: I do need the dot product, for performance. If you're interested in why, check out my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845085/n1-dim-boolean-masking-a-n-dim-array-with-array-of-means-as-desired-output
Also, I'd really like to understand what's happening here.